# How to rotate an element on both axes with different angle values

Tags: qt, qml

If you need to rotate an element in QML in order to achieve a sort of 3d flip effect then you can do

```
transform: Rotation { origin.x: 30; origin.y: 30; axis { x: 0; y: 1; z: 0 } angle: 24 }
```

How can I achieve the same thing but this time rotate both x and y with different angle values?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [transform](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#transform-prop) property of `Item` is a list, so you can apply multiple rotations:

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 200
    height: 200

    Rectangle {
        width: 100
        height: 100
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        color: "red"

        transform: [
            Rotation { origin.x: 30; origin.y: 30; axis { x: 0; y: 1; z: 0 } angle: 24 },
            Rotation { origin.x: 30; origin.y: 30; axis { x: 1; y: 0; z: 0 } angle: 60 }
        ]
    }
}
```

[image]